# Modifying the Windows Explorer Toolbar with WinApi / c++

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi, windows-explorer

My task is to program change sorting parameter of files and folders in my operating system.
In the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/nse-folderview) on the MSDN:

under

- Modifying the Windows Explorer Toolbar

indicated

- **In addition to modifying the Windows Explorer menu bar**, you can also add buttons to the toolbar. And an example code.

But example **of this modifying the Windows Explorer menu bar** is not there, the only thing is there it's button adding example.

An [alternative article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/developing-with-windows-explorer) has an example of opening it, so my question is: is it even possible, and if it is, how to do it?

Comment: Customization of Explorer toolbar doesn't work  on Windows Vista or later operating systems: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellbrowser-settoolbaritems

Comment: What's your Windows version?

Comment: If you are developing for new Windows version, for adding a button (like on old command bar) you can check context menu to see if it meets your use case. Refer to [Extending the Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/extending-the-ribbon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder sort settings are saved to:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
```

The entries look like:

[image]

You would need to loop through all of these registry entries and change the 'Sort' key.  This would only affect folders which have already been accessed.

If you want to see how these lists are parsed, run [ShellBagsView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_bags_view.html) while running [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and log all the interactions with the registry.

To do it, not programatically you can follow these instructions:
https://superuser.com/a/1481763/1043059